# Как сделать распределение данных по определенному периоду в Google таблицах (динамически при добавлении, изменении)?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w8GSKNTem7...
в листе 9 документа есть таблица с диапазоном дат и значением по этим датам, лист 8 - распределение значений по каждой дате полного диапазона (1 год).
Как должно быть (столбик "Ответ"):

с 01.01.2021 по 04.03.2021 - значение 67
с 04.03.2021 по 09.09.2021 - значение 78 ... и т. д. до конца фиксированного списка (1 год - по дням)

Есть решение (лист 8, столбики ""Выборка, "Выборка 2"), которое работает при условии, что кол-во диапазонов на листе 9 - статическое (задано 5 диапазонов), если задать 6, 7...., то надо менять формулу, при уменьшении тоже.
Надо решение, при котором добавляя или уменьшая кол-во диапазонов(строк с диапазонами), значения будут автоматически проставляться в таблице листа 8.
Заранее всем благодарен за идеи.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не давайте внешних ссылок. Особенно на документы, которые могут быть изменены или удалены. Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным.